# document.getElementsByName NOT working in some websites in webview in android

Tags: javascript, android-webview

i build new android app and use  java script syntax document.getElementsByName('') to insert value in input field in web page . but  not working in some web page that i load it in web view in android studio

here the code

```
 webCollection =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webCollection);

 webCollection.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webCollection.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);



  webCollection.loadUrl("mywepSite");

               webCollection.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                   @Override
                   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                       super.onPageFinished(view, url);


  view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByName('j_username')[0].value='myUser';document.getElementsByName('j_password')[0].value='MyPassword';document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]();})()");

                   }
               });

           }
       });
```

### here the input field

```
<input name="j_username" tabindex="1" class="form-control input-lg margin-bottom" id="j_username" spellcheck="false" type="text" size="15" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" data-required="Please enter required fields.">

<input name="j_password" tabindex="1" class="form-control input-lg margin-bottom" id="j_password" spellcheck="false" type="text" size="15" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" data-required="Please enter required fields.">
```

Comment: please provide your activity class code from where you call the web view. And also the javascript console error

Comment: this cosde inside oncreare method

Comment: after several hours i found the solution . i used the method onLoadResource instead of  onPageFinished . becuase some website take time to load . so getElementsByName return nul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a working class that can load a webview successfully

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;

public class Main extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
                // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
                onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }

}
```

Dont forget to add Permission

```
<uses-permission `android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s because you are accessing a local variable inside a inner class. Just make webCollection final.

```
final WebView  webCollection =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webCollection);
```

Any local variable, used but not declared in an inner class must be definitely assigned before the body of the inner class.

also check for the permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Explanation in The Java Language Specification, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3

Comment: i tried it bu still not working :   final    WebView webCollection =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webCollection);

Comment: please provide which error its showing.without error its tough  to tell whats the problem actually is.do you have this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />?

Comment: the strings 'myUser' and  'MyPassword' not insert in the input field . also this error appear in run in android " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined", source: myWebSite "

Comment: can you please define username and password in variable like this . : mWv.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementByName('wifi_ssid').value = '" +mEtSSID.getText().toString() + "';");  LAso check your layout code. username and password filed both have same name.

Comment: please check you input filed names.Both the input field has same name name="j_username" . and in your activity you use j_username and j_password filed.

Comment: the permission already has added . also i used your code . but still not working

Comment: did you changed the input filed names accordingly in your java code? now what error   is showing?

Comment: this error : Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByName is not a function", sourc

Comment: then the page you are loading in this activity does that page layout have the element that you are searching. and also i can see that you are setting user name and password manually.why ?its tough unless you post your activity code and layout xml

Comment: @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        String password = "a123345";
       view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
               "document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value = '" + password + "'; " +
               "})()");
    }         can you try in this way

Comment: did you changed your layout file reference names?is there any duplicate name?<input name="j_username"> you used this twice in your layout.change it and try.

Answer (score 0):

```
webCollection.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
super.onLoadResource(view, url);
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByName('j_username') 
[0].value='myUser';document.getElementsByName('j_password') 
[0].value='myPassword';document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]();})()");
}  
});
```